# How to protect time-dependent save data for mobile games

Tags: c#, android, ios, mobile, unity-game-engine

I'm working on an incremental game that runs on iOS and Android. The mechanic involves calculating the player's progress while the application is not actively open. With this comes the risk of the player changing the device's clock time to cheat. I would like to consult what approaches can be done to protect such time-dependent data?

The thing I'm considering is the use of server storage where the timestamps are recorded getting the correct value of time-elapsed after the application is restarted, but I'm curious for any alternatives. If it's of any help I'm using Unity 3D for my development. Looking forward to your suggestions.

Comment: when you tag unity3d use unity3d tag and not unity, people will downvote you for that

Comment: also this has been asked many times before, there's got to be something to be found using search

Comment: JRowan, ok got it. I'll take note of that next time. LearnCocos2D, I've searched for existing threads beforehand, but the most common response was to setup a server script that the client app will communicate for remote storage. My aim is to look for more alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into [Google Play Game Services](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/games.html) cloud saving feature alot of apps use that for exactly what you are talking about, i use [Prime31 Plugins](https://prime31.com/) but theres also some free ones out there you would have to search